# Multicore processing on Neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm currently running a script in python to make inserts and deletes however these need to be done in order so I can't use python's multiprocessing.

The script spend 95% most of time executing cypher commands and only uses 1 core.

Is there a way to enable multi-core processing in neo4j?

Comment: If they need to be executed in order, the requirement is the same client-side or server-side.

Comment: Cypher does not support multi-core processing yet, see this [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364713/neo4j-use-only-one-core-in-cypher-query-running/41364905).