# Neo4j use only one core in Cypher query running

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When i run a Cypher query in UI, only one core in server is going up and the query gets stuck or responds very slow.

I use Neo4j 3.0.7 Community.

Someone have idea what i can tune for using all cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single Cypher query is limited to a single thread. See this [tweet](https://twitter.com/darthvader42/status/670154181064400897) from late 2015 by [Stefan Armbruster](https://neo4j.com/blog/contributor/stefan-armbruster/):

> A cypher statement is (in most cases) one transaction and therefore only on one thread.

If your query is slow, you can use various tricks for optimizing it: this [blog post](https://neo4j.com/blog/tuning-cypher-queries/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll check in the post! It little bit strange, that  query can use only one thread ... for example i try to inject csv file with 100k or 1M of row data and in the query i build 2 nodes and 1 relationship per row with using arrays inside ... So i can go to eat, to sleep and may be in next day this file will be in the DB ... So look like this DB not so good for big data sets:(

Comment: @user3558218 Neo4j handles big data sets just fine - but you need to take some extra steps. There are several approaches for batch importing, including the [shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools) and the [ParallelBatchImporter class](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.1/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/unsafe/impl/batchimport/ParallelBatchImporter.java). These run outside a transaction and hence are able to utilize multiple cores. As a result, they are much faster - 100k-1M rows should be loaded in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank a lot! Great tool!